# Chamar função PHP em botão onClick HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html

Quero chamar uma função PHP que tenho na mesma página, no botão HTML.

A minha função PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['insert']))
{
    insert();
} 
function insert()
{
    $requete = "INSERT INTO \"event\" (
                title,
                start,
                end,
                description
                ) 
                VALUES
                (
                \"$txttitle\",
                \"$txtstart\",
                \"$txtend\",
                \"$txtdescription\"
                )";

    $resultat = $base_hndl->exec($requete);
    return $resultat;                                                               

    echo "feito";

}
```

E o botão HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="insert()">
    <input type=submit required  name='insert' value=save>
</form>
```

---

Estou a tentar fazer isto. Um novo botão, e um novo formulario para mostrar os dados.

```
            function select($dir, $base){       
                $base_hndl  =   new SQLite3($dir.$base);                
                $requete    =   "SELECT id, title, start, end, description FROM \"event\" ORDER BY id DESC";    
                $resultat   =   $base_hndl->query($requete);     
                $affiche    =   $resultat->fetchArray();

                echo "<br><label><b>ID: $affiche[id]</b></label><br>";
                echo "<label><b>Title: $affiche[title]</b></label><br>";
                echo "<label><b>Start: $affiche[start];</b></label><br>";
                echo "<label><b>End: $affiche[end]</b></label><br>";
                echo "<label><b>Description: $affiche[description]</b></label><br>";

            }

if(isset($_POST['mostrar']))
            {
               select($dir, $base); //affiche évènements 
            }
```

E o botão

```
<input type=submit value=Mostrar name='mostrar' >
```

Porque não funciona? é por ter dois formulários?

Comment: Nesse caso basta deixar o `action` do form vazio ou `action="#"`

Comment: Se o PHP estiver noutro ficheiro tem de fazer `<form method="post" action="nome_do_ficheiro.php">`, senão é fazer como o __perdeu__ disse.

Comment: é mesmo isso, estou a usar umas caixas de texto nesse mesmo form, para chamar na funçao, e inserir numa db. Basta chamar $txttitle. O name da input é txttitle.

Comment: Todos os elementos(inputs, radios, selects etc) devem estar dentro da tag `<form>`, para resgatar os valores no php use `$_POST['nome_do_input']`. Não tem nenhum `exctract()` por ai?

Comment: Porque a tag JavaScript e a referência a onClick?

Answer (score 10):

O código tem vários erros

1 - Remove as aspas duplas dos nomes de tabelas e campos a menos que algum nome utilize alguma palavra reservada do sqlite nesse caso use: backstick(``` `` ```), aspas duplas(`""`)  ou ainda colchetes (`[]`). [documentação](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)

mude:

```
INSERT INTO \"event\"
```

e as demais ocorrências para:

```
INSERT INTO event
```

1.1 - Para especificar valores em campos do tipo texto(char, varchar, character etc) utilize somente aspas simples (`''`).

mude:

```
   VALUES(\"$txttitle\",\"$txtstart\",
```

Para:

```
   VALUES('$txttitle', '$txtstart',
```

2 - Escopo, as variáveis externas/globais não podem ser acessadas dentro uma função elas precisam ser passadas como argumento.

Leitura obrigatória : [escopo de variáveis](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.scope.php)

Mude a assinatura da função para receber os argumentos:

```
function insert(){
  //código....
}
```

para:

```
function insert($txttitle, $txtstart, $txtend, $txtdescription){
  //código....
}
```

3 - Ao deixar em branco atributo `action` ou adicionar o valor `#` o formulário é enviado para ele mesmo.